# SQL for selecting second row on given condition

Tags: sql

A table in snowflake. We have few ref_id's. Each ref_id is associated with n no.of ord_id with corresponding status.

| ref_id | ord_id | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| R1 | 03 | Close |
| R1 | 01 | Active |
| R1 | 02 | Active |
| R2 | 07 | null |
| R2 | 04 | Close |
| R2 | 05 | Active |
| R3 | 08 | Close |
| R3 | 09 | null |

I want to have a new column latest_status which will have the status of highest ord_id for each ref_id. One more condition is that if the status is null for highest ord_id  and if its second highest ord_id status is Active then latest should have active status.

Expected result:

| ref_id | ord_id | status | latest_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| R1 | 03 | Close | Close |
| R1 | 02 | Active | Close |
| R1 | 01 | Active | Close |
| R2 | 07 | null | Active |
| R2 | 05 | Active | Active |
| R2 | 04 | Close | Active |
| R3 | 09 | null | null |
| R3 | 08 | Close | null |

Can someone please help me with the sql for this ?
I have tried below sql but it is failing for the R2 red_id result.

select distinct ord_id,status,
IFF(status is NULL,NTH_VALUE(IFF(status IN ('Active','Renew'),status,null),2)OVER(PARTITION BY ref_id ORDER BY ord_id desc),
FIRST_VALUE(status)
OVER(PARTITION BY ref_id ORDER BY ord_id DESC))as latest_status from table where ref_id='R2'

Comment: Have you tried anything so far that you can post?

Comment: What is the column format of order_id? You are showing it as string, so what is the logic for determining the "highest" order id?

Comment: Hi, I have added the query which i tried. ord_id is integer and this is in snowflake

Answer (score 0):

Not fully tested and @isolated's question will be something to bear in mind, something like so.  I've used a table var @t which will be your source.  You dont say what DBMS you are using either, so there will be some short-cuts possible i imagine.

```
select * ,
(select sts from @t as t3 where t3.ref=t1.ref and t3.ord=
(select max(ord) from @t as t2 where t2.ref=t1.ref) ) as LATEST
from 
@t as t1
```

Answer (score 0):

I could get it by doing below

```sql
select distinct ord_id,status,
    FIRST_VALUE(IFF(status is NULL,
                    IFF(B.next IN('Active','Renew'),next,null),status))OVER(PARTITION BY A.ref_id ORDER BY ord_id DESC)as latest from table A LEFT JOIN 
(select distinct ref_id,FIRST_VALUE(status)OVER(PARTITION BY ref_id ORDER BY ord_id desc) as next from table where status is not null)B on A.ref_id = B.ref_id;
```